# How to swap the positions of Min and Max in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, swap

Here in the code I found the `min` and `max` values of any given array . Now I want to swap their positions, and print them out. Like `Min` at position of `Max` and vice versa.  How can I change their positions? I have done it wrong, I guess.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
    int min = array[0]; 
    int max = array[0]; 
    int indexOfMin = 0; 
    int indexOfMax = 0; 
    int arrSize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); 
    int temp = 0; 

    cout << "Enter an array: "; 

    int k;
    for(k = 0; k <= arrSize; k++){ 
        cin >> array[k];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){ 
         if(array[i] >= max ){          
            max = array[i];            
            indexOfMax = i;            
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){ 
        if(array[i] == min){           
            continue;
        }
        if(array[i] < min){
            min = array[i];
            indexOfMin = i;
        }
    }

    temp = min;
    min = max;
    max = temp;

    cout << array[k] << " " <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input = `1, 5, 9, 1, 2, 9, 1, 3`
Output = `9, 5, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3`

Comment: Use `std::swap` in conjunction with the value returned from `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: `array[indexofMin] = max;` and `array[indexOfMax] = min;`.

Comment: I think I have done that in the end

Comment: `cout << array[k] << " " <<endl;` does not produce the output you claim. Consider a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Dr.lackedu how are you compiling this code? Are you familiar with how to step through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, but a little

Comment: Why do you need 2 separate loops to find min and max element?

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::minmax_element()` returns iterators, so `std::iter_swap()` would make more sense than `std::swap()`: "*Swaps the values of the elements the given iterators are pointing to.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh yeah.  I always forget about `std::iter_swap()`.  Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: And how can I use `std::iter_swap()` to swap the elements ?

Comment: @Dr.lackedu [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a985ddd6befbbc1e) is how you would do it using modern C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int min = array[0];
> int max = array[0];
> ```

You don't know that yet. `array[0]` at this point of the program is `0` ... but `0` might not be an element of the array after user input.

> ```
> int indexOfMin = 0;
> int indexOfMax = 0;
> ```

Indexes into and the sizes of objects in memory should be of type `std::size_t` (`<cstddef>`) because it is guaranteed that `std::size_t` is big enough. There is no such guarantee for `int`.

> ```
> int arrSize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
> ```

Use `std::size()` (`<iterator>`) for clearer code:

```
auto const arrSize{ std::size(array) };
```

> ```
> int k;
> for (k = 0; k <= arrSize; k++) {
>     cin >> array[k]; 
> }
> ```

Valid array indexes range from `0` to < `N` for an array `array[N]`. You access the array out of bounds. Use `k < arrSize` as condition. `k` should be of type `std::size_t`.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
>   if (array[i] >= max) {
>       max = array[i];
>       indexOfMax = i;
>   }
> }
>
> for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
>   if (array[i] == min) {
>       continue;
>   }
>   if (array[i] < min) {
>       min = array[i];
>       indexOfMin = i;
>   }
> }
> ```

If you had defined `int min = array[0];` and `int max = array[0];` after user input you could start these loops with `i = 1`. The `if (array[i] == min) { continue; }` buys you nothing. In contrary it wastes time with an additional comparison. Also, both loops can be combined into one:

```
int min{ array[0] };
int max{ array[0] };

std::size_t indexOfMin{ 0 };
std::size_t indexOfMax{ 0 };

for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < arrSize; ++i) {
    if(array[i] < min) {
        min = array[i];
        indexOfMin = i;
    }
    else if(array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
```

> ```
> temp = min;
> min = max;
> max = temp;
> ```

Will swap the values of the variables `min` and `max`. Also, if swapping the minimal and maximal values in the array could be done that way, why remember their position? Try

```
temp = array[indexOfMin];
array[indexOfMax] = array[indexOfMin];
array[indexOfMin = temp];
```

> So at the end i just write
>
> ```
> for (k = 0; k <= 7; k++) {
>     cout << array[k] << " " << endl;
> }
> ```
>
> ?

No, you write

```
for (std::size_t k = 0; k < arrSize; k++) {
    std::cout << array[k] << " ";
}
std::cout.put('\n');
```

because you (should) have declared the previous `k` from the input loop inside the for-loop and you make it a good habit to declare and define variables as close to where they're used as possible. Also, since you want a list in one line don't use `std::endl` inside the loop but print a `'\n'` afterwards.

Comment: So at the end i just write `for (k = 0; k <= 7; k++) {
        cout << array[k] << " " << endl; 
    }` ?

Comment: @Dr.lackedu I put that question of yours at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You already have the indices of where the max and min are found. You also have the max and min. To swap the max and min values in the array is trivial with that information. Use:

```
array[indexofMin] = max;
array[indexOfMax] = min;
```

### Suggetions for improving your code:

#### 1. Fix the problem of accessing the array

```
for(k = 0; k <= arrSize; k++){ 
    cin >> array[k];
}
```

is a problem since you are modifying `array` using an out of bounds index. Change it to use `k < arrSize`.

#### 2. Fix initialization of `max` and `min`

You need to initialize `max` and `min` only after the array has been populated with user input. Move the lines

```
int min = array[0]; 
int max = array[0];
```

to right after the loop to read the data.

#### 3. Use just one loop for computing the max and the min

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){ 
     if(array[i] >= max ){          
        max = array[i];            
        indexOfMax = i;            
    }

    if(array[i] < min){
        min = array[i];
        indexOfMin = i;
    }
}
```

#### 4. Remove the code to swap max and min

The lines

```
temp = min;
min = max;
max = temp;
```

swap the values of `max` and `min` but they don't change the contents of the array.

#### 5. Use a loop to print the array

Instead of

```
cout << array[k] << " " <<endl;
```

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){ 
   cout << array[k] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: "You already have the indices the max and min are found." no he does not. Not for `min`

Comment: @Slava, You are seeing something that I am not seeing, or vice versa.

Comment: . o O ( i see things you both don't see - hah! )

Comment: Now I am getting no answer at all

Comment: @RSahu OP initialized `min` and `max` before getting actual values into array. So for this data `min` is 0

Comment: @Dr.lackedu Last time i checkt you already got ***3*** answers??

Comment: @Slava, I see. Thanks for the sharp eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have this code:

```
int min = array[0]; 
int max = array[0];
```

yes this is common technique to point them first to the first element, but you need to use actual values, not values you used to initialize data. In your data set (all positive) you will always have `min == 0` as a result, and `indexOfMin` always pointing to 0.

The thing is you do not actually need to keep value for `min` and `max` as indexes are enough:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arrSize; i++) {
    if (array[indexOfMax] < array[i]) 
       indexOfMax = i;
    if (array[indexOfMin] > array[i]) 
       indexOfMin = i;
```

}

and now you can swap them:

```
std::swap( array[indexOfMax], array[indexOfMin] );
```

or use temp if yo are not allowed to use standard library.

Comment: And how to print the new array ?

Comment: @Dr.lackedu RSahu showed you at the bottom of his answer.