# How to find the index No. of mininum no. in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

I have to print out the index of minimum number only if they are odd . I have the code but i get the wrong answer ? This is the full code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
int array[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  
int min = array[0]; 
int max = array[0]; 
int indexOfMin = 0; 
int indexOfMax = 0; 
int found = 0; 

cout << "Enter the array: "; 

int k;
for(k = 0; k <= 7; k++){ 
    cin >> array[k];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if(array[i] <= min){
        min = array[i];
        indexOfMin = i;
    }

}
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++){
    if(array[i] % 2 != 0){
    found = (array[indexOfMin] % 2) != 0;
    }
    else{
        found = 0;
    }
}
if(found == (array[indexOfMin] % 2) != 0){
    cout << indexOfMin << min << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "not found";
}

return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in the last `cout`

> 0, 5, 9, 1, 2, 9, 1, 3 .for this given array the answer should be 3 and 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863194/how-to-swap-the-positions-of-min-and-max-in-an-array) gets the min and max indexes of the array.  Why can't you just you what you did there and remove the finding the max part?

Comment: I dont need the max part

Comment: So just remove it.

Comment: I only need to find the mininum , check if it's divisible by 2 and then print its index number?

Comment: There is no Max involved in this code

Comment: `min` seems uninitialized.

Comment: I'm talking about you previous question.  You already have the code in there to find the minimum element and it's index.  Jut reuse that part of your code.  Then check if it is divisible by 2 and you're done.

Comment: Do you want to check if min is `odd`, or if there is an odd number in array ?

Comment: That's what I have done in the code

Comment: Yes I want to check if the min is odd, If its odd then print its index

Comment: are you sure yo dont want to print out the minimum odd number

Comment: No i need to print the index of it

Comment: is [this](http://cpp.sh/9bxea) what you are trying to do?

Comment: for example  enter an array 0,5,9,1,2,7,1,3 ..The min numbers here are at position 3 and 6 . So my output should be 3, 6

Comment: From the array it is already understood that there are multiple minimum numbers

Comment: no just 3 and 6

Comment: Example corrected @Blastfurnace

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're printing the minimum value if *any number* is odd.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if(array[i] % 2 != 0){
    found == 1;
    }
}
```

This code looks at every number in the array, setting the flag if any one of them is odd. You only need to check the one number. So you can replace the above code with the following:

```
found = (array[indexOfMin] % 2) != 0;
```

or more elegantly

```
found = array[indexOfMin] & 1;
```

...assuming that you actually found a value, which won't happen if you didn't initialize `min` properly. From your example, it looks like `min` is initialized to zero. You should use a large number, such as `INT_MAX` to make sure that `array[0]` is always less than `min`, or explicitly set `min` to `array[0]` *after it's initialized* and then skip testing `array[0]`.

**Note** At present, your code contains an additional error. If you're going to initialize `min` to `array[0]` you need to do so after `array[0]` contains valid data, not beforehand. The code as written will print the wrong index if the user enters `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: mininum is intialized

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. If you want to edit your initial question to add that initialization to the code, I will be happy to trim my answer down, and we can delete these comments also.